# Selecting container type at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, metaprogramming, type-deduction

I want to select one of the standard containers with one template parameter at compile time. Something like

```
    template<typename T>
    void foo()
    {
        using Container = std::conditional_t< std::is_same_v<T, int>, 
                std::vector, // T is int
                std::set>;    // any other T
        Container<T> bar;
    }
```

How to do this properly?

Comment: What do you mean properly? And what's wrong with your example?

Comment: I'm trying to choose one of two classes, each of which is a template, and then, for example, instantiate it with a parameter. Using std::conditional leads to errors like 'expected a type, got 'set'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way seems to be

```
using Container = std::conditional_t< std::is_same_v<T, int>, 
            std::vector<T>, // T is int
            std::set<T>>;
Container bar;
```

`std::conditional_t` allows you to select a *type*. There is no standard conditional template that would allow to select a *template*. You can write one if you want but this won't be convenient to use.

```
template <bool t, template <typename...> typename X, template <typename...> typename Y>
struct conditional_template;

template <template <typename...> typename X, template <typename...> typename Y>
struct conditional_template<true, X, Y>
{
    template <typename... ts> using type = X<ts...>;
};

template <template <typename...> typename X, template <typename...> typename Y>
struct conditional_template<false, X, Y>
{
    template <typename... ts> using type = Y<ts...>;
};

template <typename... ts>
using Container = conditional_template<true, std::list, std::vector>::type<ts...>;

Container<int> x;
```

It doesn't seem possible to define an analogue of `std::conditional_t` convenience alias.

Answer (score 3):

Solution with `std::conditional_t` might be OK (and it was fixed in other answer), but IMHO it is better here use something more primitive: simple old fashioned template specialization:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void foo()
{
    using Container = std::set<T>;
    Container<T> bar;
    someCode(bar);
}

template<>
void foo<int>()
{
    using Container = std::vector<T>;
    Container<T> bar;
    someOtherCode(bar);
}
```

Comment: an excellent solution if you need to choose different code depending on the container

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what "properly" means in your question, what you probably want is the following:

```
template<typename T>
void foo()
{
    using Container = std::conditional_t< 
            std::is_same<T, int>::value,
            std::vector<T>, // T is int
            std::set<T>>;    // any other T
    Container bar;
}
```

Your original code did not work, because

- `std::conditional_t` needs types as 2nd and 3rd parameters, but you spcified class templates instead.
- There is no `std::is_same_v` in C++14, it arrived in C++17. You need to use `std::is_same<X,Y>::value` instead.

Full code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/sMhx7nod9).